# React Set interval to change quotes

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to set a interval to display just one quote at time, changing every 5 seconds.There is a simple way to do that?

[image]

I'm using Gatsby with Wordpress, querying the acf fields whith graphQL:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import citatimg from '../../images/tango_citat.svg'
import { CitatWrapper } from './styles/CitatStyles'

const Citat = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      wordpressPage(wordpress_id: { eq: 47 }) {
        acf {
          citat_1_text
          citat_1_author
          citat_2_text
          citat_2_author
        }
      }
    } 
  `)

  return (
    <CitatWrapper>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <img src={citatimg} alt="quote" />
            //quote one
            <h6>{data.wordpressPage.acf.citat_1_text}</h6>
            {data.wordpressPage.acf.citat_1_author}
            // quote 2
            <h6>{data.wordpressPage.acf.citat_2_text}</h6>
            {data.wordpressPage.acf.citat_2_author}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CitatWrapper>
  )
}

export default Citat
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run fetch at regular intervals using react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139615/run-fetch-at-regular-intervals-using-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can use `setInterval` with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks to iterate through an array of options one at a time (and go back to the start once reaching the end)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import citatimg from '../../images/tango_citat.svg'
import { CitatWrapper } from './styles/CitatStyles'

const Citat = () => {
  // destructure the “acf” field for easier reference
  const { wordpressPage: { acf } } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      wordpressPage(wordpress_id: { eq: 47 }) {
        acf {
          citat_1_text
          citat_1_author
          citat_2_text
          citat_2_author
        }
      }
    } 
  `)
  
  // structure our data in a more formal/usable format
  const quotes = [
    { text: acf.citat_1_text, author: citat_1_author },
    { text: acf.citat_2_text, author: citat_2_author },
  ]
  
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // every 5000ms (5s)
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      // `prev` will be the current value of the state; using
      // the callback here means we avoid our useEffect hook 
      // being evaluated on each state update which would be
      // bad for performance.
      setActiveIndex(prev => 
        // if we're at the end, start again at the beginning,
        // otherwise increment the index
        prev + 1 >= quotes.length ? 0 : prev + 1
      )
    }, 5000)
    
    // we return a cleanup callback that will stop the timer
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [quotes])
  
  // set the activeQuote here to avoid duplicating logic and 
  // to make it clear what is being rendered below
  const activeQuote = quotes[activeIndex]

  return (
    <CitatWrapper>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <img src={citatimg} alt="quote" />
            <h6>{activeQuote.text}</h6>
            {activeQuote.author}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CitatWrapper>
  )
}

export default Citat
```

Comment: Hi @coreyward!! I'm trying to implement a pervious button. 
This is the logic im using:
 
` const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prev =>
      prev == !0  ? prev - 1 :  prev + 1 
    )
  } `

but it´s not workin perfectly. Can you help me?

Comment: `prev == !0` evaluates to `prev == true`, which evaluates to `true` anytime `prev` is non-zero.

Comment: Hi @coreyward!! Can you help me in this? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66808162/why-my-map-fuction-dont-works-in-an-array/66808201?noredirect=1#comment118097643_66808201[link]

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
 const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prev =>
         // if we're at the beginng, go to the end,
        // otherwise decrement the index
        prev === 0 ? 2 : prev - 1
    )
  }
```