# Why my map fuction dont works in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My map dont appears in my component. I'm trying to make a carousel to show phrases and authors (one testimonial / author at time). I put the map in an array but it doesn't work. I have no idea what the best approach would be. I need a little help.

useQuoteQuery.js: (grabbing the data)

```js
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

export const useQuoteQuery = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query QuoteQuery {
      wpPage(databaseId: { eq: 13 }) {
        id
        ACF_HomePage {
          socialProve {
            testimony
            author
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return data
}
```

on graphql: (it works perfectly)

[image]

Quote.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQuoteQuery } from '../../hooks/useQuoteQuery'
import QuoteImg from '../../images/quote.svg'
import { Content, Wrapper } from './Quote.styles'
import { BiRightArrow, BiLeftArrow } from 'react-icons/bi'

const Quote = () => {
  const {
    wpPage: { ACF_HomePage: data }
  } = useQuoteQuery()

// edited - map return array but returns: Array(3)
// 0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element) ......
  
const quotes = data.socialProve.map(quote => {
return <li key={quote.toString()}>{quote.socialProve}</li>
  })

  // set interval
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(prev => (prev + 1 >= quotes.length ? 0 : prev + 1))
    }, 5000)

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [quotes])

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)

  const activeQuote = quotes[activeIndex]

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prev => (prev + 1 >= quotes.length ? 0 : prev + 1))
  }

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prev => prev - 1)
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Content>
        <img src={QuoteImg} alt="aspas" />
        <h6>{activeQuote.testimony}</h6>
        <p>{activeQuote.author}</p>
        <BiLeftArrow
          size="20"
          className="button-arrow"
          onClick={handlePrevClick}
        >
          Anterior
        </BiLeftArrow>
        <BiRightArrow
          size="20"
          className="button-arrow"
          onClick={handleNextClick}
        >
          Próximo
        </BiRightArrow>
      </Content>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default Quote
```

the result:

[image]

There is no error in the vs code terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The `quotes` array is wrapping the array produced by the `.map` in an extraneous array. Remove the extra array around the result of the `.map`:

```
const quotes = data.socialProve.map((quote) => {
  return <div key={quote.toString()}>{quote.socialProve}</div>;
});
```

Comment: Sure! Map returns an array. I accessed here to delete the question but the damage has already been done ahhahhah

Comment: its returning: `0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: "[object Object]", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: "[object Object]", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: "[object Object]", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
length: 3`

Comment: And even fixing the array, I think it will show up all at once in the component

Comment: Problems remain :(

Comment: @RicardodePaula Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66808162/edit) your question to show what the code and the output looks like now.